# How any concurrent user can use tomcat 6

Tags: tomcat6

I have created a web application, now I need to deploy my dynamic web application on tomcat 6.I want to know how many user can log in to my application at one time.

Comment: It depends entirely on what your application is, and what kind of server is running it. There's no way to answer this in general.

Answer (score 1):

your application can be accessed by any number of users at the same time only condition is how many request your server can compute. I mean the threads can be created till the server memory is available.
You can refer to this link visit http://www.tomcatexpert.com/ask-the-experts/simultaneous-users.